# how to discover all possible ways in which two tables can be joined to produce significant results

Tags: sql, database, math, join

Given two tables(only data), I want to find out all possible ways in which the two tables can be joined to produce significant results. Each way corresponds to a mapping of attributes from one table to the other. The strength of a join for a mapping M from table T1 to T2 is the percentage of rows from T1 that join to some row of T2 under the mapping M. I am interested in finding all the mappings that have support greater than a threshold t. This is a very expensive operation since the number of possible mappings is exponential in the number of attributes. Thus, I am thinking to consider sampling techniques for join discovery.

For **example**, consider [TPC-H](http://www.tpc.org/tpch/) benchmark database. Say we were given the tables for **customer** and **orders** relation. We have raw data. We dont know what each attribute corresponds to. Now by seeing the data, we should be able to derive that customer.customer_id and orders.customer_id are **join columns with high support** but not customer.customer_age and orders.customer_id. Similarly we should find all joins possible and order them according to their support. Since checking every possible combination of attributes is very costly we need an efficient technique to be used.

Real use-case: I am given a raw huge dataset where columns are isolated(assume 2 tables are there for simplicity). I want to discover what are the joins possible from it with support value efficiently. 
(Note: Since I dont know anything about type of attributes, I am thinking to consider all of them as strings and use sampling)

**I am clear that sampling is required. My questions are only the following.**

What is a good sampling strategy here? What metadata should be computed to decide the sample sizes? Can the sampling of each table be done independently or should they be correlated?

Comment: "the number of possible mappings is exponential in the number of attributes": Well, no.  In a typical real-world database, the types of the columns will vary, and a join isn't meaningful or useful unless you're joining on columns of the same type.  That makes me think this *isn't* a typical real-world database... so what exactly is it?  Can you explain your use case in greater detail?  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Kevin I have edited the question and added more detail

Comment: First, "exponential" and "polynomial" are not the same thing.  For single columns from both tables, there are n * m possibilities, decidedly not exponential.  Second, you should decide on which database you are using.  MySQL and Postgres are not both appropriate tags on this question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Since it is about database as such, it is not restricted to any particular database system. I will probably remove both tags. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to analyze the statistical properties of each single column. This way you would discover that `customers.id` and `orders.cust_id` have similar distributions and you would not even *try* to match `orders.item_count` against `customers.age`:

```
                          min    max    average    variance ...
orders.item_count         1      29     3.1782     ...
customers.age             18     75     38.45      ...
customers.id              17239  29115  23177      ...
orders.cust_id            17445  29037  23491      ...
```

Moreover, these properties can be derived from a sampling of each table, without examining the whole table. But for a proper estimation of support, you would need to do a uniform sampling, which can be as expensive as an additional full table scan. However, you would only do this if the statistical properties look promising. Your cost would be n + m + k(n*m) with a hopefully small k.

I know this isn't much, but perhaps it might be a start.

(This is *one* of many possible meaning of *significant*: "the two columns refer to the same entity". Your mileage may vary).

**Update**: MySQL isn't very well suited for the preliminary elaboration, where we actually use no RDBMS features at all. You might consider running the initial analysis using e.g. Hadoop.

## How to go about it

One piece of data which is required is a ballpark estimate of the number of rows in tables A and B. Otherwise, things get really hairy (and performance goes out of the window).

1. Begin scan
   At this point we have read *one* row and we know what fields will be in table A. We also know that table A has one billion rows, and we know (from the features of our system) that we can't afford to read more than ten million rows, nor write more than one million.

So we start reading table A skipping every 100 rows (1 bil/10 mil). We will sample one row every 1000 (1 bil/1 mil). So we will save one row in ten (1000/100) into SampleA. While we read, we accumulate statistical data on every column, i.e. we have in memory, for every column, a list of values such as Col12_Min, Col12_Max, Col12_Sum, Col12_SumSquare, ... . We can add other heuristic parameters, such as Col12_Increasing and Col12_Decreasing, and we add 1 to Col12_Increasing every time the value we read is more than the previous one, we add 1 to _Decreasing if it is less. This allows to quickly recognize "counter" rows if the table is clustered.

The whole concept of sampling/reading one row every N requires that the table has no regular distributions at that frequency: if, for example, column 23 contains a customer ID except once every hundred rows, when it contains a zero, by reading that column with period 100 we will read all zeroes, and come to wrong conclusions. If this is the case, I'm sorry; there are too many requirements, and to satisfy them all you can't use shortcuts - you need to **read every row**. A complicated enough case can't be solved in a simple way.

But supposing the case is more realistic, we do the same for table B, which goes into SampleB.

When finished, we have two much smaller tables, information on the columns, and a problem.

The "free for all" join is a matrix such as

```
        ACol1  ACol2  ACol3 ... AColN
BCol1     ?      ?      ?         ?
BCol2     ?      ?      ?         ?
BCol3     ?      ?      ?         ?
...
BColM     ?      ?      ?         ?
```

By examining the maxima, minima, and other parameters of the columns, as well as their data type, we immediately strike out all matrix cells where data types do not match, or statistical parameters are too different the ones from the other.

```
        ACol1  ACol2  ACol3 ... AColN
BCol1            ?                 
BCol2     ?             ?          
BCol3                   ?         ?
...
BColM                   ?
```

But now what can we expect when we join SampleA.cust_id against SampleB.cust_id? SampleA contains only one customer every *thousand*. So when attempting to join SampleA and SampleB, we can expect getting no more than a 0.1% match. Given a customer ID from SampleB, the likelihood of it having been harvested in SampleA is 1/1000.

We can now run an additional check: verify whether the columns are unique or not. We will see that SampleA.cust_id is unique, while SampleB.cust_id is not. This tells us that the join, if it holds, will be one-to-many.

Supposing we know (from statistical data) that SampleA.cust_id contains numbers in the range 10000000-20000000 and holds 53000 rows, and SampleB.cust_id contains numbers in the same range and holds 29000 rows; if the two columns were *not* correlated, *but* had those parameters, we would expect that generating one number at random in a range ten million wide (which we do when we extract a row from SampleB and read its cust_it) would have a probability of 53000/10000000 = 0.53% of matching a row in SampleA.

The two probabilities are different enough (always supposing we're dealing with uniform distributions) that we can try and use them to discriminate the two cases.

When we have sufficiently restricted the number of column pairs, we can run a "fake join test" by reading again the whole A (another full table scan) and verifying that all the values of SampleB.cust_id are indeed present.

**Important**: if either table is *incomplete*, i.e. the join is not "perfect" in the original tables, this will introduce an error. If this error is large enough, then it will no longer be possible to tell two columns' relation by comparing probabilities. Also, some distributions may conspire so that the probabilities are close enough to prevent a definite answer either way. In all those cases, you need to come up with some different heuristic, based on the actual nature of the data. You can't expect to find a "universal joining algorithm".

**Also**: all of the above holds for *one column vs one column* relations. Composite keys are a different can of worms altogether, and statistical analysis, while possible, will require very different tools - BigData, and something akin to OLAP - and above all, very different (and massive) processing costs.

Comment: @Iserni My assumption is that I only have raw dataset. So to learn distribution I need to do sampling as you said. What are the sampling strategies I should try and should it be done independently are the issues.

Comment: But you *do* have the columns isolated, don't you? You perform an initial full scan of both tables, gathering statistical information for each column. Then you have some hint as to which columns are probably promising joins. These columns you try to "sample join" - e.g. you take a record in ten, or so.

Comment: yes columns are isolated. only that we dont know what each column corresponds to.  The tables are too huge to do a full scan in reasonable time. Only sampling can be done to learn the distribution.

Comment: I have a doubt in learning distribution by scanning data completely. Say we do complete linear scan of data and learnt some distribution. But why customer.id and orders.cust_id should have same distribution? For example there could be customers who did not place any order. I think the join columns may not have same distribution. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. In my example not all customers place orders. But *most* do, and on large numbers that's enough for both maxima and minima to be "in the same ballpark", and even more so for the average. This assumption fails if you use a partition of the table; that's why you need to perform at least one full table scan and a uniform sampling. Otherwise you risk sampling an area of table A with no relation to the sampled area of table B. Same would go if, for example, the two tables covered very different time periods. In those cases I'm afraid very little could help you.

Comment: @Iserni Ok. Say one full table scan is done and by seeing the distribution I prune some combinations. Coming to the problem you mentioned, should the sampling be done independently or should it be correlated for the two tables? How do I decide on the sample size which is universally good?

Comment: That's a bit tricky. And alas, there is very little in this world which is *universally good* or really *one size fits all*. Amending answer...

Comment: @Iserni thanks for the amended answer. You have given a direction for me to proceed. If i understood it correctly, I will do a complete linear scan of tables T1 and T2 first(if not complete scan atleast sample with big sample size) and learn the statistical distribution of values of all cols. Then I will eliminate some of the invalid combinations of T1.col vs T2.col straightaway. Then with remaining combinations, I need to check for joins. For that I take samples from T1.col, T2.col and try joining. How do I do that? For each sample I take in T1.col should I scan T2.col till I find a match?

Comment: No, at that point you try a JOIN from the two samples SampleA and SampleB, and use the result to estimate. To have the real result you need to run the JOIN on the parent tables. If they are stored s o mewhere that doesn't support joins... things get difficult. It is a different question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

What assumptions can you make going in? If this is a big blob o’ data about which you can assume **nothing**, then you’ve really got your work cut out for you.

Matching datatypes. Integers do not join on strings; dates do not join with floats. Ditto, precision. 4 byte integers do not join with 2 byte integers; 50-max strings do not match with 128-max strings. If you’re converting everything to strings… how do you tell binary from integer from floating point from time from string to Unicode?

"Significant" statistical correlation depends on the type of relation. Stats for (One to one), (one to one-or-more), (one to zero or more), (one to zero or one) are all doable, but they don’t look like each other. Can you rule out (many-to-many) in your data?

Without scanning all the data, any sampled statistics are in doubt. Was the data was ordered by one column? What if sparse data clumped somewhere, making it appear more prevalent than it is?

Big big assumption: joins occur between single columns. If there’s “compound column identifiers” (and it does happen), and you factor in order (col1 + col2 vs. col2 + col1), it gets much, much more complex than an (m *n) analysis. You did indicate that you know anything about this  data that you picked up…

Without some reasonable starting assumptions or guesses, you just won’t get anywhere on a problem like this without serious time and effort.

Comment: you are correct. We should make some assumptions. First, the dataset is present in text files and attributes from relations T1 & T2 can be compared by string comparison. Say I compared date with age, then after significant number of samples, I will come to know that the support is very low and disregard this combination.

Comment: The data can not be assumed to be ordered by one column. Though composite key joins are possible, first I should be able to pick up single column joins with high support by taking only limited number of samples.

Comment: Back at my desk after four days. I hope the above assumptions got added to the question proper!

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with a metric of "matchedness".  Let's say it is the number of *values* that match divided by the total number of values in both tables.

You can readily generate the SQL you need as something like:

```
select max(name1) as name1, max(name2) as name2,
       count(*) as totalvalues,
       sum(in1) as totalvalues_table1,
       sum(in2) as totalvalues_table2,
       sum(in1*in2)/count(*) as measure
from (select value, max(name1) as name1, max(name2) as name2,
             max(inone) as in1, max(intwo) as in2
      from ((select 'col1' as name1, NULL, col1 as value, 1 as inone, 0 as intwo from table1 t1) 
            union all
            (select NULL, 'col1', col1, 0, 1 from table2 t2)
           ) tt
      group by value  
     ) v;
```

The "measure" gives some indication of overlap, at the values level.  You could use `sum()` to get rows -- but then you have a problem that some tables have many more rows than others.

You can then automatically generate the SQL for all columns using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table, which is available in most databases (all real databases have a similar method for getting metadata, even if the view/table name is different).

However, I think you might quickly find that this problem is harder to define than you think.  Play around with tables of different sizes and different amounts of overlap to see if you can come up with a good heuristic.